# Can I safely use a temporary branch to facilitate a push request?

Tags: git

I am a relative newcomer to Git, so go easy, please!

I have a repository rep1, from which I have cloned rep2, and from rep2 I have cloned rep3.

All three repositories are non-bare and have the default "master" branch.

I obviously found out that Git complains if I push from rep3 (because the destination is a checked-out branch), so I set up a new branch app2:downstream, pushed to that instead, and then merged app2:downstream into app2:master. So far so good - there are no doubt other ways of doing it, but this one has the appeal of relative simplicity.

Subsequently I made changes in rep1, and pulled those changes into rep2, and from rep2 into rep3 (so obviously the "master" branch in all 3 repositories has changed, but not the rep2:downstream branch).

Now the next time I made changes in rep3 and tried the trick of pushing them to app2:downstream, Git understandably complained, because app2:downstream had in the meantime become "behind" app2:master. I guess I could have merged app2:master into app2:downstream to get it up to date, but it seemed simpler and cleaner to simply run the following commands :

(in rep2)

```
git branch -D downstream
git branch downstream
```

and then push from rep3 to rep2:downstream and merge rep2:downstream into rep2:master.

I tried this out, and it worked as expected. Given that I will never use that "downstream" branch for any purpose other than facilitating these push updates, is there any possible danger or drawback to using a branch in this temporary fashion?

Comment: TBH I don't understand why you would do any of this. What's your reason for having three hierarchically cloned non-bare repos from which you push into each other? Is there any reason you can't use the "normal" method of simply having one upstream bare repo?

Comment: @l4mpi I understand your comment, and the reason for three repos is that the top one comes from an external open-source project. the middle one is the release environment for our customised version of that project, and the bottom one is our development environment.  I probably could have made rep1 and rep2 bare repositories, and may well do in future. But I think the basic question is still reasonable.

Comment: I'm not sure that the basic question is reasonable because as the official FAQ says ["never push into a repository that has a work tree attached to it, until you know what you are doing."](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_won.27t_I_see_changes_in_the_remote_repo_after_.22git_push.22.3F)  Depending on the specific requirements you might be better served with a single repository with different branches; e.g. an `upstream` branch tracking the OS repo, a `dev` branch branching from upstream (plus feature branches), and `relase_$version` branches for the releases branching from dev.

Comment: You really are setting yourself up for a lot of pain here. It might be reasonable if Git worked in ways other than it does—Mercurial, for instance, can do what you want without a lot of crazy contortions—but Git doesn't work that way. Make a bare repo.